# Unity-How Do I make a High Score?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a survival shooter game, and I'm trying to make it so when I kill an enemy it adds points to my score. The score is added to the high score and it is saved after each play. I have the script to add score, but I don't think I'm doing high score right. Could someone help me with this please?

```
public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int score;
    public static int highScore;

    Text scoreText;
    Text highScoreText;

    void Awake ()
    {
        scoreText = GetComponent <Text> ();
        highScoreText = GetComponent<Text>();
        score = 0;
        highScore = 0;

        highScoreText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("High Score", 0).ToString();
    }
    void Update ()
    {
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + score;
        highScoreText.text = "High Score: " + highScore;
        if(score>PlayerPrefs.GetInt("High Score", 0))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("High Score", score);
            highScoreText.text = score.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the enemy health script for adding to score when enemy dies.
It's in the enemySinking function.

```
public class EnemyHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int startingHealth = 100;
    public int currentHealth;
    public float sinkSpeed = 2.5f;
    public int scoreValue = 10;
    public AudioClip deathClip;


    Animator anim;
    AudioSource enemyAudio;
    ParticleSystem hitParticles;
    CapsuleCollider capsuleCollider;
    bool isDead;
    bool isSinking;


    void Awake ()
    {
        anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
        enemyAudio = GetComponent <AudioSource> ();
        hitParticles = GetComponentInChildren <ParticleSystem> ();
        capsuleCollider = GetComponent <CapsuleCollider> ();

        currentHealth = startingHealth;
    }


    void Update ()
    {
        if(isSinking)
        {
            transform.Translate (-Vector3.up * sinkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }


    public void TakeDamage (int amount, Vector3 hitPoint)
    {
        if(isDead)
            return;

        enemyAudio.Play ();

        currentHealth -= amount;

        hitParticles.transform.position = hitPoint;
        hitParticles.Play();

        if(currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            Death ();
        }
    }


    void Death ()
    {
        isDead = true;

        capsuleCollider.isTrigger = true;

        anim.SetTrigger ("Dead");

        enemyAudio.clip = deathClip;
        enemyAudio.Play ();
    }


    public void StartSinking ()
    {
        GetComponent <UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent> ().enabled = false;
        GetComponent <Rigidbody> ().isKinematic = true;
        isSinking = true;
        ScoreManager.score += scoreValue;
        Destroy (gameObject, 2f);
    }
}
```

But I am facing two problems:

1. When I restart the game, the high score text replace the score text
2. When I kill enemies the score text is not updated

Comment: Why do you think you are not doing it right? What's the problem with this code? You need to be more specific and show what you have noticed when debugging the code

Comment: What is your question? What is the problem? Where is the code for adding score?

Comment: I'm just not sure how to store my high score. I just added the script for adding score.

Comment: I'm wondering if I have to set my high score equal to my score and then set a condition that if the score is greater than high score, I should stop connecting them.

Comment: Please clarify what your expected result is and what's going wrong now

Comment: Ok. I want the normal score to count up on the screen, and the high score to count up with it on another part of the screen, and when I stop the game and play again, the high score is up on the screen. But when I play, the high score text replaces the score text, and it doesn't count up when I kill an enemy.

Comment: There's no need to keep updating the highscore every frame you should only save the new highscore at the end of the game. You can get the highscore at the beginning of the game and then just use that value during the game and when the game is over you update the value of the highscore.

Comment: I got what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to keep updating the highscore every frame you should only save the new highscore at the end of the game. You can get the highscore at the beginning of the game and then just use that value during the game and when the game is over you update the value of the highscore

You also never assigned any value to your `highScore` it was always 0. It would also be easier to put both your text component public and add them in the inspector.

```
public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public static int score;
public static int highScore;

public Text scoreText;
public Text highScoreText;

void Awake()
{
    score = 0;
    highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("High Score", 0);

    highScoreText.text = "High Score: " + highScore;
}
void Update()
{
    scoreText.text = "Score: " + score;
    highScoreText.text = "High Score: " + highScore;
    if (score > highScore)
    {
        highScoreText.text = "High Score: " + score;
    }
}
}
```

Then wherever you end the game add the code that saves the highscore.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment:

> When I stop the game and play again, the high score is up on the
>   screen. But when I play, the high score text replaces the score text,
>   and it doesn't count up when I kill an enemy

The reason why your score is not increasing when you kill enemies is because you are not calling `StartSinking ()` when your enemy dies. And as I see in that method is where you change the value of `ScoreManager.score`

```
public void StartSinking ()
{
    GetComponent <UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent> ().enabled = false;
    GetComponent <Rigidbody> ().isKinematic = true;
    isSinking = true;
    ScoreManager.score += scoreValue;
    Destroy (gameObject, 2f);
}
```

So you should add somewhere in `Death()` a call to `StartSinking ()`.

```
void Death ()
{
    isDead = true;

    capsuleCollider.isTrigger = true;

    anim.SetTrigger ("Dead");

    enemyAudio.clip = deathClip;
    enemyAudio.Play ();
    StartSinking();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> when I stop the game and play again, the high score is up on the screen. But when I play, the high score text replaces the score text, and it doesn't count up when I kill an enemy

You have two `GetComponent<Text>()`'s in your code. They seem like they're referencing the same component, resulting in your high score overwriting your score text. Try creating empty gameobjects to hold each text element, then using a `public Text scoreText` and `public Text highScoreText` and dragging the two gameobjects into the appropriate places in this script in the Unity editor.

E.g. [Heirarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnWpu.png),  [Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qup24.png)

Furthermore, you're not actually updating your high score. As your text components rely on your underlying score variables, you can't start with text and leave the high score 0. You need to make sure you update your variables then update the text based off of them, otherwise you can start off your text with the high score but then it gets instantly rewritten to 0 again in the next `Update()` as your high score hasn't been updated.

Something like the following should be what you need:

in `Awake()`:

```
// get high score from PlayerPrefs
highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("High Score", 0);
```

in `Update()`:

```
void Update ()
{
    scoreText.text = "Score: " + score;
    if (score > highScore)
    {
        highScore = score;
        // only update high score text when it actually changes
        highScoreText.text = "High Score: " + highScore;
    }
}
```

Once game finishes:

```
int originalHighScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("High Score", 0);
// compare current session's high score vs our recorded high score from prefs
if (highScore > originalHighScore)
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("High Score", highScore);
}
```